# Odoo 11 - Qweb Templating hide or show if certain choice is picked

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-11

I'm trying to custom online recruitment web page on Odoo. And the requirement is to show a field if a certain value is picked in the field. 
The field is Many2one field type, so when a applicant pick a record from that field how can i show the hidden field when a certain value is picked?

EDIT:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="university_id" name="university_id">                
        <t t-foreach="universities" t-as="university">
              <option id="university" t-att-value="university.id"><t t-esc="university.name"/></option>
              </t>
    </select>
</div>
```

So when a certain value was picked from the drop down, it will show a form so user can fill it.

Comment: Can you please share your code here for which you want to add this?

Comment: I've edited the answers, thanks for the attention.